# SignalR vs setTimeout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

Part of my MVC view page gets refreshed every 30 seconds after fetching some resource from the server. I've been using setTimeOut to trigger a javascript method to fetch data from the server asynchronously, compare it with the old data, and if it has changed, update a div tag. Now, I'm thinking of creating a timer in global.asax class, start it in the application_start event, and in the timer elapsed event, get the data, and send it to all the clients using SignalR only if the data has changed.

Will there be any advantage in using SignalR over setTimeOut here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advantage in this case would be you'll avoid an unnecassary trip to the server if that data hasn't changed. Using SignalR, you can broadcast the data to all clients only when the data has changed.

The other advantage, is that SignalR will push from the server to the browser using the best technology available, without you having to worry about it. This could be WebSockets if you're running your server on Windows 8 server with ASP.NET 4.5 (probably a future consideration), or Server Sent Events if the client is Chrome, Firefox or Opera, or Forever Frame if the client is IE. Either way, you don't have to worry about it, SignalR will take care of the transport management for you.

Depending on where your data is stored and how it's updated, you might even be able to do away with the timer completely, and just broadcast the data to all clients immediately whenever it's changed. If it's updated by another action method on a controller, just broadcast to clients from there. If it's updated via some other process directly into the DB, you could setup a SQL query notification in you application (in App_Start) to get alerted when it's changed and then broadcast at that point.

Comment: Thanks Damian! I don't have a proper handle on the data, it's in a different server, and only if I fetch it I'll know whether it has changed or not, only so I decided to go with a timer.

Comment: Cool. Even if it's on a different server, you could set up a web-service endpoint in your app that the different server can send to when the data changes, and in the code for the web-service, do a broadcast to all clients. But if timer suits, that's fine too :) Just be sure you use a System.Threading.Timer.

Comment: After comparing the data, I'm using Hub.GetClients<MyHub>().javascriptMethod(msg) to broadcast; is there anyway I can find whether there are any connected clients, so that I can avoid the data fetch from the other server if there are no clients? If you see, in the case of setTimeout, data will be fetched only if a user lands on the page having the setTimeout.